# I'm completely new to python, and was just practicing lists, and I tried running a for loop

Tags: python, list

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
newlist = []

for x in fruits:
  if "a" in x:
    newlist.append(x)

print(newlist)
```

*ABOVE CODE WORKS*

So I tried running a for loop. What I'm trying to do is, I have 2 lists, and if there is something in my list that contains "a", and if it contains "a", it will be added to the second list

So I did this, just to practice my skills on lists and found that it does not work:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
newlist = []

for x in fruits:
  if "a" in x:
    newlist.extend(fruits)

print(newlist)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'mango', 'apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'kiwi', 'mango']


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

And I want someone to explain to me step by step what is happening, why I am wrong, and what other methods I can use to get the output I want

**WANTED OUTPUT FOR NEWLIST:**

```
['apple', 'banana', 'mango']


** Process exited - Return Code: 0 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

Comment: `newlist.extend(fruits)` says "take the entire contents of the `fruits` list and add them *all* to `newlist`".  You want `newlist.append(x)`, which says "add just `x` to `newlist`."

Comment: In the first code you are calling `newlist.append(x)`, and in the second code you are calling `newlist.extend(fruits)`.  Those are completely different.  Why did you think they would work the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between Python's list methods append and extend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `newlist.append()` instead of `extend()`. I believe the `extend()` method adds all of the elements inside an iterable, in this case the original list.

Also, you are using `fruits` as a parameter for `extend()`. This is wrong by itself and defeats the purpose of iterating through your list elements. You should instead use the variable `x` in this case if you want to go through your list.

Answer (score 0):

In the first iteration of the loop:
`x="apple"`
and the condition `if "a" in x` is `True`

What `newlist.extend(fruits)` does is adds all the contents of fruits which is `["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]` into the newlist.

On the 2nd and 5th iteration (i.e `'banana'` and `'mango'`) the contents of the fruits list (all the fruits) is again added to the newlist.

As a result, when you `print(newlist)`, it prints all the fruits repeated 3 times.

Answer (score 0):

you are using extend function which adds all elements. So basically , if any String in fruits contains a all Strings will be added.

Answer (score 0):

Basically:

- `.append()` will add every word containing the letter "a" to the newlist.
- `.extend()` will add the whole list every time it finds a word with the letter "a".

Three words with the letter "a" in the original list, so the whole list was added three times as well to newlist.

Keep practicing in due time you will be able to avoid using `.append()` as well in certain situations like:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry", "kiwi", "mango"]
newlist = [x for x in fruits if "a" in x]
print(newlist)
```